# Closed set $\mathbb{R}^2 _{\geq0}$

Tags: real-analysis

Is the set {$\underline{x}^{'} \in \mathbb{R}^2 _{\geq0}: x_1^{'}+x_2^{'} \leq x_1 + x_2 $}   $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^2_{\geq0}$

a closed set? If so how do I show this?

Comment: Your definition doesn't make sense. Perhaps you mean, for a particular point $x\in \Bbb R^2_{\geq 0}$ ?

Comment: Why does it not make sense?

Comment: Variables must be quantified before they are used. But if you just do the stupid fix (move your quantifier to the front), then you are defining an entire family of sets, not a single set.